# How to compare multiple columns and set values based off of it

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I Reference to the picture in the link below, I need to find the best way to compare which Start Month and End Month row the current month is between and then set a cell somewhere else in the spread sheet based of Rental Increase value of that row. What is the most efficient way to do this without writing a million IF() statements?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic3sh.jpg

Answer (score 1):

`VLOOKUP()` is made for tasks like this. It will take a rectangular range look up a given value in the first column, and return the value in the same row from a different column.

In your example, if the first visible cell ("Current Month") were cell `A1`, then I'd write the formula like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, B2:D6, 3, TRUE)
```

`A2` is your reference value, `B2:D6` is the range for the lookup. Excel will look up the value in the first column of that range (column `B`), match the greatest value that's less than or equal to `A2` (in this case, 0) and return the value that's in column 3 of the range (in this case, `$3,099.22`). `3` specifies that you want the third column.

`TRUE` specifies that you want to do a range lookup (the default behavior). If you set that to FALSE, it will look for an exact match and return `#N/A` if it's not found. This makes `VLOOKUP()` work as a poor man's table join.

Be aware that if you're doing range lookups like this, your data have to be in order or else you'll get unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `VLOOKUP()` function for finding the rental increase value based on the row range match, something like this:

```
=vlookup(A2, B2:D6, 3, TRUE)
```

*assuming the cells in the picture are placed at A1.*

This should return the rent increase in the cell where you put the formula.